# jQuery script running a function when it shouldn't be

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have hacked together this jQuery script and it is all working fine except that the alert is being fired when it shouldn't be, and I can't work out why.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){              
function countDouble() {      

  var d = $("input.double:checked").length;
  var s = $("input.single:checked").length;

    if (s === 1 && d === 2) {

        $("a#proj-btn").attr("href", "#tab2");

    } else {

        $("a#proj-btn").attr("href", "http://www.someurl.com.au/new-cruise-name-home");
        $("#proj-btn").click( function() {
            alert('Please select which projects you are interested in before continuing with enquiry.\nSelect 1 x 1 day project and 2 x 2 day projects by ticking the box beneath your chosen projects.');
        });
    };
}
countDouble();
$(":checkbox").click(countDouble);  
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="right"><a id="proj-btn" href="#">NEXT &gt;&gt; Cabin Choice</a></li>
</ul>
```

So when there is 1 x .single checkbox checked and 2 x .double checkboxes checked, it adds the URL of #tab2 to the button which works fine.
But it also displays the alert 3 times after clicking the button when the checkboxes are checked. The alert should only be when the checkboxes are not checked.
What have I done wrong? I can't work this out

Comment: why are you adding the event handler for `$("#proj-btn").click(` inside that function? - every time it gets called, it gets added again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Unbinding 'click' every time you call `countDouble()`  and pulling `countDouble()` outside of the ready function (probably not necessary).

```
function countDouble() {      
  var d = $("input.double:checked").length;
  var s = $("input.single:checked").length;

  //Add This:
  $("#proj-btn").unbind('click');

  if (s === 1 && d === 2) {

        $("a#proj-btn").attr("href", "#tab2");

  } else {

        $("a#proj-btn").attr("href", "http://www.someurl.com.au/new-cruise-name-home");
        $("#proj-btn").click( function() {
            alert('Please select which projects you are interested in before continuing with enquiry.\nSelect 1 x 1 day project and 2 x 2 day projects by ticking the box beneath your chosen projects.');
        });
  };
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){              
    countDouble();
    $(":checkbox").click(countDouble);  
});
```

Comment: That worked Michael. And of course it seems pretty obvious now :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){              
function countDouble() {      

  var d = $("input.double:checked").length;
  var s = $("input.single:checked").length;

    if (s === 1 && d === 2) {

        $("#proj-btn").unbind("click");//changed
        $("a#proj-btn").attr("href", "#tab2");

    } else {

        $("a#proj-btn").attr("href", "http://www.someurl.com.au/new-cruise-name-home");
        $("#proj-btn").click( function() {
            alert('Please select which projects you are interested in before continuing with enquiry.\nSelect 1 x 1 day project and 2 x 2 day projects by ticking the box beneath your chosen projects.');
        });
    };
}
countDouble();
$(":checkbox").click(countDouble);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See this form to move adding your event handler outside the function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#proj-btn").click(function () {
        alert('Please select which projects you are interested in before continuing with enquiry.\nSelect 1 x 1 day project and 2 x 2 day projects by ticking the box beneath your chosen projects.');
    });

    function countDouble() {
        var d = $("input.double:checked").length;
        var s = $("input.single:checked").length;
        if (s === 1 && d === 2) {
            $("a#proj-btn").attr("href", "#tab2");
        } else {
            $("a#proj-btn").attr("href", "http://www.someurl.com.au/new-cruise-name-home");
        }
    }
    countDouble();
    $(":checkbox").click(countDouble);
});
```